# How to pass event and other arguments in grid's context menu item handler?

Tags: events, dojo, contextmenu, handler

I'm using Dojo 1.5, and I'm trying to create a context menu that can invocate a function **myFunction** passing the event and other arguments. So far I've the following code:

```
    <div dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="bankerMenu" style="display: none;">
        <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" onclick="copyDocuments('bankerFolder');" iconClass="dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy">Copy to Client</div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.PopupMenuItem" onclick="doNothing()" iconClass="dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy">
                <span><s:text name="CopyTo.label"/></span>
                <div dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="bigsubmenu">
var="distributionList">
                        <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" onclick="myFunction(event,'bankerFolder',1)"><s:property value='distributionListName'/></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

But it is not recognizing the 'event' that I want to pass to the function. I know I can susbtitute the call using this:

```
            <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" label="Some menu item 2">
                <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
                    myFunction(evt,'bankerFolder',1);
                </script>
            </div>
```

but I would like to simplify it and used the first syntax. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `event` literally would likely end up leaving you at the mercy of cross-browser inconsistencies.  However, since events connected through Dojo worry about this for you, and since `onClick` is a widget event that already receives the event object as an argument, you should be able to get away with the following:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" onClick="myFunction(arguments[0],'bankerFolder',1)"><s:property value='distributionListName'/></div>
```

Also note the capital C in `onClick` - widget events always use camel case; they are not actual DOM events, though they are often mapped to analogous DOM events.  I get the impression you were testing with capital C though, based on the problem you described encountering.

Here's a simplified example of the idea working (initially provided/suggested by Dustin Machi in the Dojo IRC channel): http://jsfiddle.net/xwFC5/5/

Comment: It works, thanks!! But I just realized that my problem is diferent. I've a dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid, and I have dijit.Menu created. What I really want is to know which row was selected when the user did the right click and selected the MenuItem. The event I receive does not have a rowIndex, I assume that's because it is launched by the MenuItem, not by the Grid. Any idea how can I get the rowIndex in such cases? Thanks!

Comment: To solve that, the first thing I'd think of is to connect `onCellContextMenu` (or whichever `*ContextMenu` event is appropriate), get whatever information you need from the event object passed to that function and store it somewhere (perhaps in the grid instance, or a common namespace), then retrieve and clear it in your menu event callback.  Yeah it's the long way around, but it ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

Following from Ken's comment to the answer above, I managed to figure this out as outlined here: http://blue-networks.net/wp/?p=37 It connects to `onCellContextMenu` and pulls the relevant information out of the event, saving it into the grid object.

Comment: Please post the code instead of just a link. If the link goes dead, the answer would cease to help.